# Does 439 cM shared suggest half uncle rather than half first cousin?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, relationship-analysis, half-first-cousins

I am trying to determine if my half sister had a different father than the one she grew up with. I was given a name of who the father could be.  He has passed away but his son took a DNA test on Ancestry. My half sister's son did as well.  The relationship is at 439cMs.

Is there any chance that this relationship could be a half uncle rather than half cousin?

Answer (score 2):

From [The Shared cM Project 3.0 tool v4 for 439 cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/439) the possibility of such a match being a half first cousin (Half 1C) is far greater than it being a half uncle.

Nevertheless, the latter is also possible:

> Relationship probabilities (based on stats from [The DNA Geek](https://thednageek.com/the-limits-of-predicting-relationships-using-dna/))
>
> **83.17%** Great-Great-Aunt / Uncle Half Great-Aunt / Uncle **Half 1C** 1C1R Half Great-Niece / Nephew Great-Great-Niece / Nephew
>
> 15.80% Half GG-Niece / Nephew† Half GG-Aunt / Uncle† 2C Half 1C1R 1C2R
>
> **1.03%** Great-Grandparent† Great-Grandchild† **Half** Aunt / **Uncle**† Half Niece / Nephew† 1C† Great-Aunt / Uncle Great-Niece / Nephew
>
> † this relationship has a positive probability for 439cM in
>   thednageek's table of probabilities, but falls outside the bounds of
>   the recorded cM range (99th percentile)